# MethodNotAllowedHttpException when using Ajax to post

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.6

I am trying to do an Ajax post to allow for people the test the database connection midway through the installer, but I constantly get this error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (HTTP/2.0 405)
```

In addition to:

```
{
"message": "",
"exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\MethodNotAllowedHttpException",
"file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php",
"line": 255,
"trace": [
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php",
        "line": 242,
        "function": "methodNotAllowed",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php",
        "line": 176,
        "function": "getRouteForMethods",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
        "line": 613,
        "function": "match",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteCollection",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
        "line": 602,
        "function": "findRoute",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
        "line": 591,
        "function": "dispatchToRoute",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
        "line": 176,
        "function": "dispatch",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 30,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php",
        "line": 57,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 149,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 53,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
        "line": 30,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 149,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 53,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
        "line": 30,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 149,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 53,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php",
        "line": 27,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 149,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 53,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php",
        "line": 46,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 149,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 53,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
        "line": 102,
        "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
        "line": 151,
        "function": "then",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
        "line": 116,
        "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
        "type": "->"
    },
    {
        "file": "/home/vagrant/code/public/index.php",
        "line": 55,
        "function": "handle",
        "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
        "type": "->"
    }
]
}
```

I have added the CSRF token to the Ajax setup 3 different ways. I have checked my routes via php artisan route:list. I have used both $.ajax and $.post. I have changed my routes urls so that they do not match with any get requests (Because sometimes it would return the html from the get). Lastly I disabled CSRF protection and I tested with Postman and everything  worked so something is wrong with the front end code.

Frontend code:

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'postInstall', 'class' => 'f1 install', 'method' => 'put')) !!}

                    <h3>ComedyLounge Site Installer</h3>
                    <p>Setup basic requirements for your site</p>
                    <div class="f1-steps">
                        <div class="f1-progress">
                            <div class="f1-progress-line" data-now-value="16.66" data-number-of-steps="4" style="width: 16.66%;"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="f1-step active">
                            <div class="f1-step-icon"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></div>
                            <p>Requirements</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="f1-step">
                            <div class="f1-step-icon"><i class="fa fa-database"></i></div>
                            <p>DB Settings</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="f1-step">
                            <div class="f1-step-icon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></div>
                            <p>Email Settings</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="f1-step">
                            <div class="f1-step-icon"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"></i></div>
                            <p>Confirm</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <fieldset>
                        <h4>PHP Version:</h4>
                        @if(version_compare(phpversion(), '7.1.3', '<'))
                            <div class="alert alert-warning">
                                Warning: Requires PHP >= 7.1.3 Your version is {{phpversion()}}
                            </div>
                        @else
                            <div class="alert alert-success">
                                Success: Requires PHP >= 7.1.3 Your version is {{phpversion()}}
                            </div>
                        @endif

                        <h4>Extensions:</h4>
                        <table class="table table-striped">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th>Found</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach($requirements as $requirement => $found)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>{{$requirement}}</td>
                                        @if($found)
                                            <td><i class="fa fa-check"></i></td>
                                        @else
                                            <td><i class="fa fa-times"></i></td>
                                        @endif
                                    </tr>
                                @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <div class="f1-buttons">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-next" {!! $canContinue ? '' : 'disabled' !!}>Next</button>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>

                    <fieldset>
                        <h4>Database Settings:</h4>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {!! Form::label('database_type', 'Database Type') !!}
                            {!! Form::select('database_type', array('sqlite' => 'SQLite','mysql' => 'MySQL', 'pgsql' => 'Postgres', 'sqlsrv' => 'SQLSrv'), Input::old('database_type'), array('class' => 'form-control database-selector')) !!}
                        </div>
                        <div class="database_group db_sqlite">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('database_sqlite_host', 'SQLite Database') !!}
                                {!! Form::text('database_sqlite_host', Input::old('database_sqlite_host'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'path/to/sqlite/db')) !!}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('database_sqlite_prefix', 'SQLite Prefix') !!}
                                {!! Form::text('database_sqlite_prefix', Input::old('database_sqlite_prefix'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'cl_')) !!}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="database_group db_mysql">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('database_mysql_host', 'MySQL Host') !!}
                                {!! Form::text('database_mysql_host', Input::old('database_mysql_host'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '127.0.0.1')) !!}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('database_mysql_port', 'MySQL Port') !!}
                                {!! Form::text('database_mysql_port', Input::old('database_mysql_port'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '3306')) !!}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('database_mysql_database', 'MySQL Name') !!}
                                {!! Form::text('database_mysql_database', Input::old('database_mysql_database'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'ComedyDatabase')) !!}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('database_mysql_username', 'MySQL Username') !!}
                                {!! Form::text('database_mysql_username', Input::old('database_mysql_username'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'User')) !!}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('database_mysql_password', 'MySQL Password') !!}
                                {!! Form::text('database_mysql_password', Input::old('database_mysql_password'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Password')) !!}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('database_mysql_prefix', 'MySQL Prefix') !!}
                                {!! Form::text('database_mysql_prefix', Input::old('database_mysql_prefix'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'cl_')) !!}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="database_group db_pgsql">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('database_pgsql_host', 'Postgres Host') !!}
                                {!! Form::text('database_pgsql_host', Input::old('database_pgsql_host'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '127.0.0.1')) !!}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('database_pgsql_port', 'Postgres Port') !!}
                                {!! Form::text('database_pgsql_port', Input::old('database_pgsql_port'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '3306')) !!}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('database_pgsql_database', 'Postgres Name') !!}
                                {!! Form::text('database_pgsql_database', Input::old('database_pgsql_database'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'ComedyDatabase')) !!}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('database_pgsql_username', 'Postgres Username') !!}
                                {!! Form::text('database_pgsql_username', Input::old('database_pgsql_username'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'User')) !!}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('database_pgsql_password', 'Postgres Password') !!}
                                {!! Form::text('database_pgsql_password', Input::old('database_pgsql_password'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Password')) !!}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('database_pgsql_prefix', 'Postgres Prefix') !!}
                                {!! Form::text('database_pgsql_prefix', Input::old('database_pgsql_prefix'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'cl_')) !!}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="database_group db_sqlsrv">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('database_sqlsrv_host', 'SQLSrv Host') !!}
                                {!! Form::text('database_sqlsrv_host', Input::old('database_sqlsrv_host'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '127.0.0.1')) !!}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('database_sqlsrv_port', 'SQLSrv Port') !!}
                                {!! Form::text('database_sqlsrv_port', Input::old('database_sqlsrv_port'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '3306')) !!}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('database_sqlsrv_database', 'SQLSrv Name') !!}
                                {!! Form::text('database_sqlsrv_database', Input::old('database_sqlsrv_database'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'ComedyDatabase')) !!}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('database_sqlsrv_username', 'SQLSrv Username') !!}
                                {!! Form::text('database_sqlsrv_username', Input::old('database_sqlsrv_username'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'User')) !!}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('database_sqlsrv_password', 'SQLSrv Password') !!}
                                {!! Form::text('database_sqlsrv_password', Input::old('database_sqlsrv_password'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Password')) !!}
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                {!! Form::label('database_sqlsrv_prefix', 'SQLSrv Prefix') !!}
                                {!! Form::text('database_sqlsrv_prefix', Input::old('database_sqlsrv_prefix'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'cl_')) !!}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="f1-buttons">
                            <a href="/install?testDB=yezsir" type="button" class="btn btn-left btn-testdb">Test Connection</a>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-previous">Previous</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-next">Next</button>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>

                    <fieldset>
                        <h4>Set up your account:</h4>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="f1-email">Email</label>
                            <input type="text" name="f1-email" placeholder="Email..." class="f1-email form-control" id="f1-email">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="f1-password">Password</label>
                            <input type="password" name="f1-password" placeholder="Password..." class="f1-password form-control" id="f1-password">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="f1-repeat-password">Repeat password</label>
                            <input type="password" name="f1-repeat-password" placeholder="Repeat password..."
                                   class="f1-repeat-password form-control" id="f1-repeat-password">
                        </div>
                        <div class="f1-buttons">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-previous">Previous</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-next">Next</button>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>

                    <fieldset>
                        <h4>Social media profiles:</h4>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="f1-facebook">Facebook</label>
                            <input type="text" name="f1-facebook" placeholder="Facebook..." class="f1-facebook form-control" id="f1-facebook">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="f1-twitter">Twitter</label>
                            <input type="text" name="f1-twitter" placeholder="Twitter..." class="f1-twitter form-control" id="f1-twitter">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="f1-google-plus">Google plus</label>
                            <input type="text" name="f1-google-plus" placeholder="Google plus..." class="f1-google-plus form-control" id="f1-google-plus">
                        </div>
                        <div class="f1-buttons">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-previous">Previous</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-submit">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </fieldset>

                {!! Form::close() !!}
<script>
    $(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
        });

        $('.btn-testdb').on('click', function (e) {
            console.log($("form.install").serialize());

            $.get("{{ route("postInstallTestDB") }}", $("form.install").serialize())
                .done(function (data) {
                    alert(data)
                });

            e.preventDefault();

        });
    })
</script>
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/install', [
    'as'   => 'getInstall',
    'uses' => 'InstallController@getInstaller',
]);
Route::post('/install', [
    'as'   => 'postInstall',
    'uses' => 'InstallController@postInstaller',
]);
Route::post('/install/testdb', [
    'as'   => 'postInstallTestDB',
    'uses' => 'InstallController@postInstallerTestDB',
]);
```

I don't know what I could be doing wrong, I have checked every post and tried pretty much everything. (Probably something small that I missed)

**I am using the latest version of laravel.**

Comment: Something to add is that JQuery is sending as a Get instead of a Post when I use both $.post() and $.ajax with type and method set to post. The only way around this is when I set the contentType for $.ajax but then I cannot read it in the backend as if it were a form.

Comment: which content type did you use. Have you tried 'multipart/form-data'?

Comment: I tried json as content type which worked somewhat, I couldn't access the data though. I will try the 2 you listed.

Comment: Okay I tried 'multipart/form-data' and it did the exact same thing as what happened with json as the content type.

Answer (score 0):

The response code 405 from the error message means "method not allowed".

In your frontend code you try to access the route postInstall via put, but in your routes postInstall is set as a post request.

change

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'postInstall', 'class' => 'f1 install', 'method' => 'put')) !!}
```

to

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'postInstall', 'class' => 'f1 install', 'method' => 'post')) !!}
```

Comment: Thank you that fixed my form but doesn't change anything in regards to my Ajax not working.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured out the problem, it had to do with my ajax function. My script now looks like this:

```
<script>
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
    });

    $('.btn-testdb').on('click', function (e) {

        $.ajax({
            url: "/install/testdb",
            type: "post",
            method: "post",
            data: $("form.install").serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log("error: " + data);
            },
        });

        e.preventDefault();

    });
</script>
```

**Thank you to everyone that helped.**